# MyBatis retrieve Integer as Enum from MySql DB

Tags: mysql, enums, mybatis, pojo

I hava a POJO which contains an enum property.

**[Speed.java]**

```
public class SpeedEntry implements Serializable {

    [...]

    private int idSpeed;
    private SpeedStatus status; // enum Property

    [...]
```

**[SpeedStatus.java]**

```
public enum SpeedStatus {

[...]

VALID(1), INVALID(2), UNKNOWN(0);   // Possible values.

private int value;

// Default constructor
private SpeedStatus(final int pValue) {
    this.value = pValue;
}
[...]
```

And I would like to store and retrieve the Speed object and get its properties filled as usual with MyBatis. 
The column assigned to SpeedStatus was created as an **INT(11)**.

In this case, doing the **INSERT** was quite direct accessing its internal value property with:

```
#{status.value}
```

However, retrieving the object and getting its enum value filled from the integer stored in the database has not been as easier as inserting it. I tried, without luck, using a **resultMap**:

**[speedMapper.xml]**

```
<resultMap id="speedMap" type="Speed">
        <result property="idSpeed" column="idSpeed" />
        <result column="status" property="status.value" 
            typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"/>
</resultMap>
```

So...**it is possible to achieve what I am looking for?** 
Is there any simple clarifying example around there?

What is the best alternative? Should I change the type stored in the database to "enum" ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your insert statement you direct access its internal value by

```
#{status.value}
```

By this way, you insert VALID by value 1, INVALID by value 2, NUKNOWN by the value 0.
But in your retrival statements, you using the resultMap defined by

```
typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"
```

That means you map the table **int(11)** field to Enum POJO property using the

```
SpeedStatus.ordinal()
```

Enum value will be mapped by the order defined in `SpeedStatus`. So in select statements  table field value 0 mapped to VALID, 1 mapped to INVALID, 2 mapped to UNKNOWN.

If you still want to use `EnumOrdinalTypeHandler` you should defined the Enum value equal to its `ordinal()` value.

```
public enum SpeedStatus {

    UNKNOWN(0), VALID(1), INVALID(2); 

    private int value;

    private SpeedStatus(final int pValue) {
        this.value = pValue;
    }
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the option typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler" gives me an error while loading the JAR -->  java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed invoking constructor for handler class org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler. I am currently using MyBatis-Spring and I am not loading any _ mybatis-config.xml _ file.

Comment: I have written a Unit Test just now using org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler. I have got the result I want to. I need more info to check the problem

Comment: I've got the problem <result column="type" property="status"
                typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"/>. property="status", not "status.value". Please read my answer again. Retriving mapping needs to change the SpeedStatus definition。

Comment: It seems there was some name mismatching...the key was to assign a diferent value for column and property attributes of the result label inside the resultMap: **<result column="statusValue" property="status" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.EnumOrdinalTypeHandler"/>**    With your advice it works correctly ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert your int to Enum you can define your own EnumHandler.

```
public class SpeedStatusTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<SpeedStatus> {

public SpeedStatus getResult(ResultSet rs, String param) throws SQLException {
return SpeedStatus.getEnum(rs.getInt(param));
}

public SpeedStatus getResult(CallableStatement cs, int col) throws SQLException {
return SpeedStatus.getEnum(cs.getInt(col));
}

public void setParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int paramInt, SpeedStatus paramType, JdbcType jdbctype)
    throws SQLException {
ps.setInt(paramInt, paramType.getId());
}
}
```

Now just add this typeHandler to your my batis config file,

```
 <typeHandlers> 
        <typeHandler javaType='SpeedStatus' handler='SpeedStatusTypeHandler' /> 
</typeHandlers>
```

You wont even have to mention your typeHandler in your resultMap,mybatis will take care of it whenever it comes across a SpeedStatus Enum in your Pojo.